# Run another python file, changing one of its variables

Tags: python, import

I would like to run a file1, from another file2, while changing one of its variables.
Something like this:

**file1.py**

```
a = 1
b = 1
c = 1
# Then:
# Countless functions depending on a, b, c, etc., depending on each other in complicated ways.
# Results from these functions are plotted and exported
```

**file2.py**

```
# Pseudo-code:
import file1 with (a = 0)  # runs file1, exporting all results, as if file1 had a = 0.
```

What is the simplest way to do this, considering I have too many variables, complicated functions and dependencies in file1.py?

Comment: Can you change `file1.py` to read a configuration or at least get its variables from a common module that you can import first? Changing `file1.a` after import can only effect uses of `a` after that point. `file1.py` could use some refactoring.

Comment: Yes I can. I also believe this is the best option, but not so pythonic.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you must change a global variable from another module, you can do so by writing

```
import file1
file1.a = 0
```

Note that the `import` statement will result in the execution of `file1` in its entirety, and so any module level usage of `a` by `file1` or its dependencies will use the original value (in this case, `1`).

If you need to have control over when the contents of `file1` are executed, you should move its contents to a function or class. It seems quite likely that the variable `a` in your example would be better expressed as a parameter to a function that `file1` defines.

Comment: I upvoted, but want to highlight that any use of `a` at `file1.py` s module level (e.g, `foo = [None] * a`) or by any other module that imported `file1` before you did, will cause this solution to fail.

Comment: As soon as I do "import file1", file1 is run with a = 1, plotting and exporting all results with a = 1, instead of with a = 0.

Comment: @BernardoCosta Yes, that is the expected behavior. `file1` will be run in its entirety upon being imported. If you need to interactively control its state, you'll need to put all of your code in a function/class.

Comment: This is what I want to avoid, because I have 2000 lines of code with dozens of variables and functions. I am considering to put variable "a" in a external text file. Then accessing it from file1. Then, from file2, make this external a=0, and import file1.

Comment: @BernardoCosta It sounds like you have a lot of refactoring to do then. As a quick fix, you may be able to wrap the entire script in a `main` function, which either accepts `a` as a parameter or continues to use it as a global.

Comment: I cannot do this either because I want to import some of the functions of file1 to file2, so they cannot be nested. I agree there is a bad design and refactoring everything would be the best, but it would take days, and make the code much less readable.

Comment: @BernardoCosta Can you simply move all non-global variable, non-function definition statements to `main`?

Answer (score 0):

Wrap your variables as functions, and pass in the value as a parameter.

```
def get_a(val=1):
    return val
```

then in file2

```
import file1
file1.get_a(0)
```

Comment: This doesn't help with other users of `file.a`. I think this is just a complicated way for file2 to do `a = 0`.